# How to get height of an control in ViewModel

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp, winrt-xaml

I have a ContentControl in my Xaml and I want to access it's Height in ViewModel, what I tried is created a property in my ViewModel and Bind that to ContentControl via TwoWay. But problem with that is it's setting ContentControl height to 0, which is the default value of that property.

Code:

Xaml

```
<ContentControl x:Name="ContentControl"
                Content="{Binding ContentFrame}"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                Height="{Binding ContentControlHeight, Mode=TwoWay}"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"></ContentControl>
```

ViewModel(Had property change notification using Fody):

public double ContentControlHeight { get; set; }

Comment: Can you add code you used?

Comment: You can bind Loaded event of the Content control and get height of the control

Comment: @Archana, Thanks. But I don't want to access control directly in code behind. Also see my updated post with code.

Comment: @Romasz. Thanks. Will give a try.

Comment: If you are using `Template10` in your project you can create `DelegateCommand` in viewmodel and bind it to `Loaded` event

Comment: @Archana, Yes that's a workaround, I am not using Template10 but have custom RelayCommand which I can hook up. But will be better if this can be don't directly via property binding.

Comment: Not sure if *Height* will work with binding the same as [*ActualHeight*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement#Windows_UI_Xaml_FrameworkElement_ActualHeight) (see remarks). It may be worth to try with *SizeChanged* event.

Comment: @Romasz. Thanks. Tried using SizeChanged and it worked.

Comment: @Romasz It's a good solution. You could make it as an answer.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT I was wondering if there is a better one.

Comment: @Romasz If me, I will make a custom ContentControl class, and register SizeChanged event inside it. Defining a dependency property and bind it. But the basic principle is the same with you. If make a custom class, then we don't need to register SizeChanged event every time in code-behind. Thanks for sharing your solution. According to it, I will make a reply for Zea Shah's reference.

Answer (score 4):

Add to Romasz's suggestion, @ZeaShah you could make a custom class and register SizeChanged event in it.

```
public class MyContentControl : ContentControl
{
    public MyContentControl()
    {
        this.SizeChanged += MyContentControl_SizeChanged;
    }

    private void MyContentControl_SizeChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SizeChanged: height " + e.NewSize.Height + " width: " + e.NewSize.Width);
        CHeight = e.NewSize.Height;
    }

    public double CHeight
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(CHeightProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CHeightProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for CHeight.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CHeightProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CHeight", typeof(double), typeof(MyContentControl), new PropertyMetadata(0));
}
```

Defining a dependency property and binding it in your main page:

```xml
<local:MyContentControl x:Name="ContentControl"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" CHeight="{Binding ContentControlHeight,Mode=TwoWay}">
</local:MyContentControl>
```

Answer (score 3):

Binding to [*ActualHeight*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement#Windows_UI_Xaml_FrameworkElement_ActualHeight) (and probably *Width*) is not a good choice, as:

> For purposes of ElementName binding, ActualHeight **does not post updates** when it changes (due to its asynchronous and run-time calculated nature). Do not attempt to use ActualHeight as a binding source for an ElementName binding. If you have a scenario that requires updates based on ActualHeight, use a SizeChanged handler.

It's worth to follow the above and use [*SizeChanged*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement#Windows_UI_Xaml_FrameworkElement_SizeChanged) event.